# Java TZ: Can I copy zi folder from Java 7 and paste it in Java 6?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

My application uses Oracle JDK 1.6.39 and it have a feature to convert time based on timezone.

Java 1.6.39 considers a time difference of 1 hour between "America/Eirunepe" and "America/New_York" (EST). But in reality there is no time difference between these timezones.

In order to fix this issue I found that I should run Time Zone Updater Tool (tzupdator tool) provided by oracle.

More about TZUpdater Tool: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html

Currently TZUpdater tool is available for Java7 and Java8 on
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

But my application uses Java 1.6.39 and I can't update java due to some technical reasons.

My question is:
**Can I copy Eirunepe binary file present in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/zi/America/ from latest version of java? I've tried updating it and it works, but I am not sure if it cause any other issue. Is it safe to do so?**

Any help here will be highly appreciable.

Comment: "But in reality there is no time difference between these timezones." There really is. They're not using the same rules at all. If you mean "right now they have the same UTC offset" that's a different matter.

Comment: Yeah, I mean currently they have same UTC offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to just replace the files because the internal version of zi-file-format has not changed. The whole zi-format has not changed since the very early Java-days. If you carefully study the source code of SUN/Oracle-classes `ZoneInfo` and `ZoneInfoFile` then you will see that the version is still 1.

**But please be aware of the fact that all these files have gone with Java 8** so it is only an interim solution for you as long as you are forced to use Java 6 for what ever reason. See also this [JDK-8007572-ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007572?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab).

And yes, for Java 7 you SHOULD use the tzupdater-tool.

Comment: Thank you.. It works. We can safely replace zi folder.